# SQL Insert statements in C# on Azure DB - Running very slow

Tags: c#, sql, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

I'm working on an importer in our web application. With the code I currently have, when you are connecting via local SQL server, it runs fine and within reason. I'm also creating a `.sql` script that they can download as well

**Example 1**

40k records, 8 columns, from 1 minute and 30 seconds until 2 minutes

When I move it to production and Azure app service, it is running VERY slow.

**Example 2**

40k records, 8 columns, from 15 minutes to 18 minutes

The current database is set to: Pricing tier: Standard S2: 50 DTUs

Here is the code:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        var generatedScriptFilePathInfo = GetImportGeneratedScriptFilePath(trackingInfo.UploadTempDirectoryPath, trackingInfo.FileDetail);

        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(generatedScriptFilePathInfo.GeneratedScriptFilePath))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                sqlTransaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
                        
                await writer.WriteLineAsync("/* Insert Scripts */").ConfigureAwait(false);

                foreach (var item in trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript)
                {
                    errorSqlScript = item;

                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(item, sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 800;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    currentRowLine++;
                    rowsProcessedUpdateEveryXCounter++;
                    rowsProcessedTotal++;

                    // append insert statement to the file
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                // write out a couple of blank lines to separate insert statements from post scripts (if there are any)
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(string.Empty).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(string.Empty).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OverflowException exOverFlow)
    {
        sqlTransaction.Rollback();
        sqlTransaction.Dispose();
        trackingInfo.IsSuccessful = false;
        trackingInfo.ImportMetricUpdateError = new ImportMetricUpdateErrorDTO(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId)
                {
                    ErrorLineNbr = currentRowLine + 1, // add one to go ahead and count the record we are on to sync up with the file
                    ErrorMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", ImporterHelper.ArithmeticOperationOverflowFriendlyErrorText),
                    ErrorSQL = errorSqlScript,
                    RowsProcessed = currentRowLine
                };

        await LogImporterError(trackingInfo.FileDetail, exOverFlow.ToString(), currentUserId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await UpdateImportAfterFailure(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId, exOverFlow.Message, currentUserId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return trackingInfo;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sqlTransaction.Rollback();
        sqlTransaction.Dispose();

        trackingInfo.IsSuccessful = false;
        trackingInfo.ImportMetricUpdateError = new ImportMetricUpdateErrorDTO(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId)
                {
                    ErrorLineNbr = currentRowLine + 1, // add one to go ahead and count the record we are on to sync up with the file
                    ErrorMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", ex.Message),
                    ErrorSQL = errorSqlScript,
                    RowsProcessed = currentRowLine
                };

        await LogImporterError(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ex.ToString(), currentUserId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await UpdateImportAfterFailure(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId, ex.Message, currentUserId).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return trackingInfo;
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is there any way to speed this up on Azure? Or is the only way to upgrade the `DTUs`?
2. We are looking into SQL Bulk Copy as well. Will this help any or still cause slowness on Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

**Desired results**

Run at the same speed when running it at a local SQL Server database

Comment: remember the database is far away from you...so you gotta do something to reduce round trips...bulk operation is one way to do that

Comment: @Ctznkane525 beat me to it, but your method appears consistent with the times you posted - 40k records in 15 mins, which is 900k milliseconds, is about 22.5ms per round-trip. Locally, you're running the same workload about 10 times faster, based on your posted times - or 2.25ms per round-trip - which makes sense. Can you run this from an Azure VM (local to Azure SQL DB) and see if the results are closer to your local test?

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` will massively speed things up. And the code you have has issues anyway: lack of parameterization, and missing `using` block on the transaction object

Comment: What happens if, instead of sending individual inserts, build a single command with all the inserts together and run it only once in the DB?

Comment: You're doing RBAR inserts, the slowest way to get data into a database. Send your data to the server once, process it in a single batch, see performance increase by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input! All of this helped. I posted a solution for now!

Answer (score 0):

For now, I updated my code to batch the insert statements based on how many records. If the record count is over 10k, then it will batch them by dividing the total by 10.

This helped performance BIG TIME on our Azure instance. I was able to add 40k records within 30 seconds. I also think some of the issue was how many different slots use our app service on Azure.

We will also probably move to `SQLBulkCopy` later on as users need to import larger excel files.

Thanks everyone for the helps and insights!

```
        // apply the create table SQL script if found.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript.ToString()) == false)
        {
            int? updateEveryXRecords = GetProcessedEveryXTimesForApplyingInsertStatementsValue(trackingInfo.FileDetail);
            trackingInfo.FileDetail = UpdateImportMetricStatus(trackingInfo.FileDetail, ImportMetricStatus.ApplyingInsertScripts, currentUserId);

            int rowsProcessedUpdateEveryXCounter = 0;
            int rowsProcessedTotal = 0;

            await UpdateImportMetricsRowsProcessed(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId, rowsProcessedTotal, trackingInfo.FileDetail.ImportMetricStatusHistories).ConfigureAwait(false);

            bool isBulkMode = trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript.Count >= 10000;

            await writer.WriteLineAsync("/* Insert Scripts */").ConfigureAwait(false);
            int insertCounter = 0;
            int bulkCounter = 0;
            int bulkProcessingAmount = 0;
            int lastInsertCounter = 0;
            if (isBulkMode == true)
            {
                bulkProcessingAmount = trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript.Count / 10;
            }

            await LogInsertBulkStatus(trackingInfo.FileDetail, isBulkMode, trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript.Count, bulkProcessingAmount, currentUserId).ConfigureAwait(false);

            StringBuilder sbInsertBulk = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in trackingInfo.InsertSqlScript)
            {
                if (isBulkMode == false)
                {
                    errorSqlScript = item;

                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(item, sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = 800;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }

                    currentRowLine++;
                    rowsProcessedUpdateEveryXCounter++;
                    rowsProcessedTotal++;

                    // append insert statement to the file
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(item).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Update database with the insert statement created count to alert the user of the status.
                    if (updateEveryXRecords.HasValue)
                    {
                        if (updateEveryXRecords.Value == rowsProcessedUpdateEveryXCounter)
                        {
                            await UpdateImportMetricsRowsProcessed(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId, rowsProcessedTotal, trackingInfo.FileDetail.ImportMetricStatusHistories).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            rowsProcessedUpdateEveryXCounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sbInsertBulk.AppendLine(item);

                    if (bulkCounter < bulkProcessingAmount)
                    {
                        errorSqlScript = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "IsBulkMode is True | insertCounter = {0}", insertCounter);

                        bulkCounter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // display to the end user
                        errorSqlScript = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "IsBulkMode is True | currentInsertCounter value = {0} | lastInsertCounter (insertCounter when the last bulk insert occurred): {1}", insertCounter, lastInsertCounter);

                        await ApplyBulkInsertStatements(sbInsertBulk, writer, sqlConnection, sqlTransaction, trackingInfo, rowsProcessedTotal).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        bulkCounter = 0;
                        sbInsertBulk.Clear();
                        lastInsertCounter = insertCounter;
                    }

                    rowsProcessedTotal++;
                }

                insertCounter++;
            }

            // get the remaining records after finishing the forEach insert statement
            if (isBulkMode == true)
            {
                await ApplyBulkInsertStatements(sbInsertBulk, writer, sqlConnection, sqlTransaction, trackingInfo, rowsProcessedTotal).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies the bulk insert statements.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sbInsertBulk">The sb insert bulk.</param>
        /// <param name="wrtier">The wrtier.</param>
        /// <param name="sqlConnection">The SQL connection.</param>
        /// <param name="sqlTransaction">The SQL transaction.</param>
        /// <param name="trackingInfo">The tracking information.</param>
        /// <param name="rowsProcessedTotal">The rows processed total.</param>
        /// <returns>Task</returns>
        private async Task ApplyBulkInsertStatements(
                                                     StringBuilder sbInsertBulk,
                                                     StreamWriter wrtier,
                                                     SqlConnection sqlConnection,
                                                     SqlTransaction sqlTransaction,
                                                     ProcessImporterTrackingDTO trackingInfo,
                                                     int rowsProcessedTotal)
        {
            var bulkInsertStatements = sbInsertBulk.ToString();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(bulkInsertStatements, sqlConnection, sqlTransaction))
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 800;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            // append insert statement to the file
            await wrtier.WriteLineAsync(bulkInsertStatements).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Update database with the insert statement created count to alert the user of the status.
            await UpdateImportMetricsRowsProcessed(trackingInfo.ImportMetricId, rowsProcessedTotal, trackingInfo.FileDetail.ImportMetricStatusHistories).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```